# Vector averaging wind direction using focal buffers in R?

Tags: raster, r, buffer, focal-statistics

I have a raster of 1 km wind direction data that I need to run a focal buffer on. Instead of using the default buffering mean function, I need to use [vector averaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34017216/how-can-i-calculate-wind-direction-average-in-r/34018443) since my wind direction is in degrees (e.g. (360+0)/2 = 180/South, instead of 360/North!).

I tried using the circular mean function from the circular package, but this doesn't work with rasters.

How do I perform vector average focal buffers on rasters?

I wrapped `avgWind` function around circular mean but still get the same error.

```
library(raster)
library(circular)

# creating a sample raster for stackoverflow
xy <- matrix(sample(0:359), 10, 10)
r <- raster(xy)

avgWind <- function(r, units) {
  r_avg <- mean(circular(r, units = "degrees"))
  return(r_avg)
}

r_buf <- focal(r, focalWeight(r, d=20, type='circle')
               ,fun = avgWind(r)
               ,na.rm = T)


Error in x/180 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
In class(x) <- c("circular", cl) :
  Setting class(x) to multiple strings ("circular", "RasterLayer", ...); result will no longer be an S4 object
```

**EDIT**

After applying obrl_soil's example to my projected data the buffered data appears to be inverted.

[image: 10k buffered wind direction raster]

[image: original wind direction raster]

Comment: Your fun argument needs to be an actual function.

Comment: I still get the same error after wrapping circular into its own function.

Comment: I'd usually decompose to horizontal and vertical components of the wind and average those, then calculate the direction again. Do you have magnitude as well as direction?

Comment: The syntax problem needed to fix here is delete "(r)" from "avgWind(r)" - it wants the function, not a return value from it.  (But running this code crashes R for me so  I'd check what avgWind is returning)

Comment: My 32GB workstation could handle it, but it's crashing on my 4GB laptop too. I'll look into calculating horizontal and vertical components of wind direction/magnitude and see what I can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`focalWeight` appears designed to work on a projected raster, so I think half the problems you're having actually come from the reprex you've built. Terrible irony! To build a circular filter for unprojected data, I like the method in [this blog post](https://scrogster.wordpress.com/2012/10/05/applying-a-circular-moving-window-filter-to-raster-data-in-r/):

```
make_circ_filter <- function(radius, res) {
  circ_filter<-matrix(0, nrow=1+(2*radius/res), 
                         ncol=1+(2*radius/res))
  dimnames(circ_filter)[[1]]<-seq(-radius, radius, by=res)
  dimnames(circ_filter)[[2]]<-seq(-radius, radius, by=res)
  sweeper<-function(mat){
    for(row in 1:nrow(mat)){
      for(col in 1:ncol(mat)){
        dist<-sqrt((as.numeric(dimnames(mat)[[1]])[row])^2 +
                     (as.numeric(dimnames(mat)[[1]])[col])^2)
        if(dist<=radius) {mat[row, col]<-1}
      }
    }
    return(mat)
  }
  out<-sweeper(circ_filter)
  return(out)
}


cf <- make_circ_filter(5, 1)
# for an efficient mean filter, adjust the non-NA values 
# in cf to 1/n where n is the number of non-NA cells, and
# then set NA to 0
cf[which(cf == 1)] <- 1/length(cf[!is.na(cf)])
cf[which(is.na(cf))] <- 0
```

### EDIT

Ok the technical note you've supplied has a much better solution. So here's how I would spatialise it:

```
library(raster)
library(slga)

# handy data
aoi <-  c(148.3, -21.2, 148.7, -20.8)
aspect <- slga::get_lscape_data('ASPCT', aoi )
fake_speed <- slga::get_lscape_data('SLPPC', aoi) # its really slope >.>

# then follow tech note method to average wind
rad2deg <- function(rad) {(rad * 180) / (pi)}
deg2rad <- function(deg) {(deg * pi) / (180)}

# calculate components u and v
dir_comp_u <- fake_speed * sin(deg2rad(aspect))
dir_comp_v <- fake_speed * cos(deg2rad(aspect))

# run focal on each component to get a spatial mean
avg_comp_u <- focal(dir_comp_u, cf)
avg_comp_v <- focal(dir_comp_v, cf)

# back-convert
wd_avg_rad <- calc(stack(avg_comp_u, avg_comp_v), 
                   function(cell) {
                     if(any(is.na(cell))) { 
                       NA_real_
                     } else {
                         atan2(cell[1], cell[2])
                     }})

# and then to degrees
wd_avg_deg <- abs(rad2deg(wd_avg_rad) - 180)
```

I don't really know how to interpret the output as I'm using fake data, but it seems reasonable...?

Comment: Wow this is awesome! Thank you! Would you recommend adding in the wind speed component and modifying your code to follow this example?

https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Stuart_Grange2/publication/262766424_Technical_note_Averaging_wind_speeds_and_directions/links/54f6184f0cf27d8ed71d5bd4/Technical-note-Averaging-wind-speeds-and-directions.pdf

Comment: And I'd use this method to spatially smooth aspect data as well - just leave the speed component out.

Comment: The spatial buffers are working, but the final output appears to be inverted. I've added comparison figures of my projected data, swapping `cf` for a `focalWeight` parameter. I've gone through the math several times and haven't figured out where the problem is yet.

Comment: Ditch the 180 in the last step, I guess? Exactly what to do depends on whether your origin point is at 12 o'clock or elsewhere. Different GIS apps set different origins.

Comment: I was missing a negative sign when calculating `dir_comp_u` and `dir_comp_v`. It only took me a few weeks to figure it out ha! Thanks again for all of your help on this!